# Where is the clear all notifications button on Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

After an update months ago, I no longer have a clear all button for notifications. I must manually swipe each of them away. Is there a setting I'm missing?

I'm using Nexus 4 Android 5.1.1.

Comment: Should be one at the bottom-right of the notifications pane. You may need to swipe right to the bottom of the list to get to it.

Comment: Were you using KitKat before the update? If it's, then the notification panel behaves differently, and Josh Holland is right. Otherwise, if the update was from Lollipop to Lollipop, then it's a new issue I've heard.